# How to avoid duplication in JOIN query PHP PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, group-by, left-join, distinct

I have 2 tables named as cat and sub_cat. Each sub_cat have at least one or more then one cat. I have tried to fetch both using LEFT Joins but getting duplicates of cat.

I have tried "GROUP BY" clause but getting only one sub_cat against cat
I also tried "DISTINCT" but not getting accurate result

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id AS cat_id, c.title AS cat_title, s.id, s.title,s.cat_name FROM cat c LEFT JOIN sub_cat s ON c.id = s.cat_name
```

Using group by

```
SELECT c.id AS cat_id, c.title AS cat_title, s.id, s.title,s.cat_name FROM cat c LEFT JOIN sub_cat s ON c.id = s.cat_name GROUP BY c.id
```

I expect only one cat and multiple sub_cats but getting multiple cat against multiple sub_cat

> Edited

As shown in the picture I want all the cats when user click on any of them I can get all related sub_cats
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJAIn.png)

Comment: "I expect only one cat and multiple sub_cats" ...and how would you expect that to look in the output exactly? The SQL output can only be a flat table of rows. So you will get one row for every sub_cat found by the query. If you join it to cat, then you'll inevitably get duplicate entries for any given cat if there is more than one sub_cat which matches to a given cat - because it must output all the sub_cats, and show the cat it belongs to. That's just how SQL works...

Comment: why is jor on consition c.id = s.cat_name?

Comment: @Zeljka I would expect it's just a badly-named field in sub_cat. It's joining back to the ID field in cat, so hopefully the match is on IDs and not descriptions!

Comment: However, if you can show us a demo (e.g. draw a picture) of what output you are hoping for then we might be able to help you find another way. Possibly whatever it is you want can be done either by having more than one query, or is just something which you should be doing in whatever client you are using to present this data (e.g. in a web application or whatever) - generally, presentation is a job for the UI, not the database. It's not clear if that's the problem, or you just have a misunderstanding about how SQL works.

Comment: can you show us table conf

Comment: @ADyson see the edited question

Comment: @HamzaAfzal that's your UI output, not your SQL output. The two things are not related directly. Also it's unclear from the screenshot whether what you've shown me is a list of categories or a list of subcategories? If it's a list of categories to be clicked on, then I can't see your expected result (because no subcategories are shown). If it's a list of subcategories, then I can't see the clicked category. The example is a) incomplete, and b) arguably irrelevant because the question was about SQL not HTML.

Comment: @HamzaAfzal I was asking what you expect the SQL query to return, because that's the code you asked about. If you wish to use the output of the SQL query to construct some UI, then show us the code you use to construct the UI.

Comment: How would you suggest me how to fetch all subcategories against category in PDO

Comment: I think you're looking for the solution in the wrong place. Get the output of your SQL query, and then use your PHP code to take that data, process it and turn it into the exact way you want to present it in the UI. You can either do it by getting all subcategories joined to all categories, and then just looking for unique category entries to make a category list, or by using two queries - one to get just categories, and one to get subcategories (with the category ID), and then use the result of each to create different parts of the UI. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below will help you.

```
SELECT c.id AS cat_id, c.title AS cat_title, group_concat(s.cat_name)sub_cat_name 
FROM cat c INNER JOIN sub_cat s 
ON c.id = s.cat_name 
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: Can you explain me group_concat(s.cat_name)sub_cat_name

Comment: @HamzaAfzal [take a look here](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&ei=9ZFAXOnkB7mn1fAPlOi-mAw&q=group_concat+mysql&oq=group_concat+mysql&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.843.2314..2495...1.0..0.85.567.7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i20i263j0i10j0i22i30j0i22i10i30.KYboKoVlcuY) ... :-)

Comment: @HamzaAfzal sorry to get back so late. group_concat() function groups the data in comma separated format for the given column based on the group by column